# How to filter array from one date to another in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, datepicker

I have an array of objects "mainData" like so:

```
0: {date: "2020-07-25T16:44:43.000Z"
description: "Qwerty"
id: 89329972},
1: {date: "2020-07-25T16:46:28.000Z"
description: "Place bins please"
id: 65586316},
2: {date: "2020-07-25T16:49:12.000Z"
description: "Solve sewerege problem"
id: 84687816},
3: {date: "2020-07-27T16:34:47.000Z"
description: "Test compl"
id: 56437370},
4: {date: "2020-07-28T08:40:34.000Z"
description: "Sewerage problem in my area"
id: 92402221},
5: {date: "2020-09-09T11:42:18.000Z"
description: "problem"
id: 25613902},
```

Now I am allowing the user to select from and to dates by using the mui datepicker. This is how I am receiving the values:

```
fromDate: Sat Jul 25 2020 11:43:00
toDate: Sat Aug 08 2020 11:43:00
```

Now I want to filter the array from this date to that date, including the from and to dates. I tried to do it this way but it just returns an empty array. I've put the code inside useEffect which is run every time toDate changes, Also I've used Moment to make the formats of both dates same:

```
 useEffect( () => {
        if (fromDate !== null && toDate !== null) {
            setReportData(
                mainData.filter(
                    (obj) =>{
                        

                        return Moment(obj.date).format("DD MMM yyyy") >= Moment(fromDate).format("DD MMM yyyy") && Moment(obj.date).format("DD MMM yyyy") <= Moment(toDate).format("DD MMM yyyy")
                    }


                )
            )

           

        }

    },[toDate])
```

### Edit

When I select a single date :

```
 useEffect( () => {
        if (oneDate !== null) {

            setReportData(
                mainData.filter(
                    (obj) =>{
                   

                        return new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() === oneDate.getTime()
                    }


                )
            )

        }

    },[oneDate])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object's date property can be parsed directly to `Date` object. So then you can use `getTime`.
Also, filter returns `Date` object.

So, you can change your code to this

```
 useEffect( () => {
    if (fromDate !== null && toDate !== null) {
        setReportData(
            mainData.filter(
                (obj) =>{
                    return new Date(obj.date).getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() && new Date(obj.date).getTime() <= toDate.getTime()
                }
            )
        )
    }

},[toDate])
```

If you want to consider all dates to be of local timezone, then you need to remove the last part of each date's string in order for the parse method to consider each string as local timezone date.

So previous method becomes

```
 useEffect( () => {
    if (fromDate !== null && toDate !== null) {
        setReportData(
            mainData.filter(
                (obj) =>{
                    return new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() && new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 19)).getTime() <= toDate.getTime()
                }
            )
        )
    }

},[toDate])
```

Comment: ok wow this worked, but one tiny problem, it didn't return the object on the value of toDate. Although there was on object on that date in the array. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: which object and what `toDate`?

Comment: like for example I chose fromDate 25th and toDate 9th , it should return me an array of size 6 , but instead it returns me an array of size 5 . You may refer to the mainData array in my qs.

Comment: ok then try `console.log` after your if statement to see what each property has and how it is compared to the filters.

Comment: hmmm I think it has to do with the time zone, because `new Date("2020-07-25T16:44:43.000Z")` for example will return a different date object (and time) depending on your timezone, so maybe it is correct because that object may seem to have time included in your search criteria, but that time when converted into your local timezone, will be out of your date criteria boundaries.

Comment: updated my answer and i guess the second variation will "fix" the problem you stated.

Comment: check the updated answer and especially the second code snippet with the `substring`

Comment: It works! Can you please tell me what the substring does here?

Comment: The substring actually removes the GMT info so when this date is parsed, it is considered as local time and not as GMT time so all comparisons are based on local time. Before, you had GMT times parsed and compared to local (filter) times. If my answer solved your problem, dont forget to accept it. It's the green tick. thnx :)

Comment: Also I'm sorry i'm asking a lot, but I tried the same thing when I select oneDate, and it doesnt work, Can you help me out with that as well ? i've edited my qs.

Comment: why do you have `===` when having one date and not `>=`? you want equality there?

Comment: yeah sure , Thanks a lot!

Comment: because I want, all the dates equal to that particular date the user selected

Comment: ok so you need to consider the seconds too :) or else narrow your substring to `0,16` in order not to take into consideration the seconds

Comment: hmm okay, but what if i dont wanna consider the time at all? just the day month and year? and match it that way? Is that possible?

Comment: then it needs extra code for filter too in order to "reset" time to 00:00:00. This should be posted as another question I guess, but try with `moment`  if it can "reset" the date to midnight time.

Comment: I see, but its not working even when I change it to 0,16.

Comment: a codesandbox would help here, but put as a first step a console.log of these 2 values to see what the program tries to compare in order to find the error easily

Comment: db date : 1595677440000   selected onDate : 1595665080000 ok so they are not coming the same

Comment: place also a new Date(calculated_timestamp) at console.log to better show the dates calculated. eg at your example, new Date(1595677440000) is `Sat Jul 25 2020 14:44:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)` at my local zone and new Date(1595665080000 ) is `Sat Jul 25 2020 11:18:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`

Comment: ok i think i get it, the time is the problem here. I need to remove it somehow :/

Comment: ok theres a probelm with the data i'm receiving. I have actually 5 objects of 25th date and 1 object of 26th. But when filtering the data, I receive 3 objects of 25 and 3 objects of 26. I used this to format both my dates: return Moment(obj.date).format().substr(0,10) === Moment(oneDate).format().substr(0,10)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219535/discussion-between-aldor-and-apostolos).

Answer (score 0):

We can use moment.js too. By converting the moment to expected format.

In above case we have
`Sat Jul 25 2020 11:43:00`

Moment provides locale support format using `llll`, which is similar
to this one, usage as follow.
Initialize the format constant somewhere at top, after `if` statement;

```
const format = 'llll';
```

And just replace the filter return statement with :

```
return Moment(obj.date, format).unix() >= Moment(fromDate, format).unix() && Moment(obj.date, format).unix() <= Moment(toDate, format).unix()
```

Comment: this isnt working when I try to match a single date.

Comment: Seems like that was later edit  to the question @Aldor.  Can you help me in providing the format output date of `oneDate`, so that I add up in above answer to make it useful for feature read.